# Is there a lightweight library I can use to ask users to download a modern browser?

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

I'm building a site that relies heavily on several HTML5 features. I do not want to develop a separate version of the site for IE6-8. Instead, when those users visit, I'd like a nice-looking modal to pop up to politely suggest that they visit the site with a modern browser like Chrome or Firefox. Is there an existing library that will do this for me?

Ideally, modern browsers would only have to download the browser detection code; the code powering the modal would be loaded asynchronously only when needed.

Comment: Well, ideally modern browsers should not download any browser detection code. You can use conditional comments to detect IE6-8...

Comment: Consider redirecting IE6-8 visitors to here: http://ecmazing.com/hasek/ie.html (just kidding `:P`)

Comment: So you deliberately created a site that won't work for about 15% of web users and now you want them to download and install a different browser just so they can use your site. Not exactly in the spirit of the web.

Comment: @Trevor - you're approaching this wrong: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement

Comment: @RobG and Adam: How can you say that without knowing anything about my site? My target audience isn't necessarily "all web users," and there are plenty of projects where progressive enhancement isn't realistic. Maybe it's a web-based image editor that uses canvas. Does "the spirit of the web" preclude me from even starting such a project?

Answer (score 4):

Try this: http://www.ie6countdown.com/join-us.aspx

Comment: When do we get an IE7 countdown then?

Comment: Although I found pradeek's answer to be my personal favorite, this deserves an upvote. This is a script we all should include in our webcontent,  for the good of humanity, and do with IE6 the same thing we did with [smallpox](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/PMH0002332/).

Comment: @Paul Thanks, that's good to know about, but it doesn't quite fit my use case. I could modify it to be conditional on `lt IE 9`, but upgrading to IE9 isn't an option for Windows XP users. Also, it seems a bit inefficient for the whole message to be in the page body downloaded by all browsers.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/). Instead of checking what browser they use, you can check for the exact feature that you need and display an alert if the current browser does not support it. Additionally, Modernizr also includes the [YepNope](http://yepnopejs.com/) library which lets you conditionally load resources that you need (like the modal you mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

Investigate [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) as well.

Comment: Depending on your audience, Chrome Frame could be very useful. The latest version doesn't need administrator privileges to install.

Answer (score 0):

The rule is to detect browser capabilities, not individual browsers.  As pradeek mentioned, modernizr does an excellent job of this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this will do the trick: https://github.com/viamarte/modernweb